# All possible combinations in array - recursion?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, permutation

I have a question that goes over my head, hope someone can help. I think it may have to be solved by recursion and/or permutations, but I am not good enough of a (PHP) programmer for that.

```
$map[] = array("0", "1", "2", "3");
$map[] = array("4", "5", "6", "7");
$map[] = array("8", "9", "10", "11");
$map[] = array("12", "13", "14", "15");
$map[] = array("16", "17", "18", "19");
$map[] = array("20", "21", "22", "23");
```

The $map array is limited to a max length of "6".

I am looking for a way to make all possible combinations. Here are a few VALID combinations:

Example 1:

```
$map[] = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
$map[] = array("8", "9", "10", "11");
$map[] = array("12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", );
$map[] = array("23");
```

Example 2:

```
$map[] = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23");
```

Example 3:

```
$map[] = array("0", "1");
$map[] = array("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8");
$map[] = array("9", "10", "11");
$map[] = array("12");
$map[] = array("13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20");
$map[] = array("21", "22", "23");
```

The values in each of the map arrays have to be in ascending order, e.g. this example is INVALID:

```
$map[] = array("0", "1", "4");
$map[] = array("3", "5");
etc...
```

Hope this can be done.

Comment: When you say, the map array is limited to six, then all of your valid examples have more than six...

Comment: @omar-ali The examples are the second dimension of $map.

Comment: @omar-ali he means that there are only 6 indexes in `$map` (notice `$map` is an array)

Comment: Could you add what your __end goal__ is? Maybe you are approaching this incorrectly, what are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to find the optimal groups. The values (0, 1, 2, 3, etc) refer to "scores" for a timeframe (0 = 00:00 - 01:00, 1 = 01:00 - 02:00, etc.). I can only group and "sum" these scores in to 6 "blocks" of time. I am trying to find a way which groups, or "blocks" produce the best possible total sum.

Comment: refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44097540/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive solution.

```
<?php
function combination($remaining, $current, $combinations) {
    $e = array_shift($remaining);
    $combinations[$current][] = $e;

    if(empty($remaining)) {
        print_r($combinations);
        return;
    }

    combination($remaining, $current, $combinations);
    // 6 Limit remove for all solutions
    if ($current < 6) {
        combination($remaining, $current + 1, $combinations);
    }
}


$remaining = range(0, 23);

combination($remaining, 0, array());
```

If you want to store all solutions for [0,23] you're gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want **ranges** of numbers, I simplified the question to a matter of **permutations**.

Here is a `shellscript` (that executes from the terminal as a `node.js` script) that calculates the ranges you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs

// Config
var blocksTotal     = 3;    // 6
var numbersTotal    = 6;    // 24
var perms           = [];   // Permutations

// Start the loop
(function divideHours(numbersToGo, blocksToGo, arr) {

    // What block is this? [1 .. 3]
    var block = blocksTotal - --blocksToGo;

    // Divide numbers
    if (block < blocksTotal)
        for (var hour = 0; hour <= numbersToGo; hour++) {
            if (block == 1) var arr = [];
            arr[block-1] = hour;
            divideHours(numbersToGo-hour, blocksToGo, arr);
        }
    // Last block? Assign rest of numbers
    else {
        perms.push(arr.concat([numbersToGo]));
        console.log(arr.concat([numbersToGo]).toString());
    }
})(numbersTotal, blocksTotal);
```

Testing with a smaller set of ranges and numbers, you get the following permutations:

> 0,0,6
>   0,1,5
>   0,2,4
>   0,3,3
>   0,4,2
>   0,5,1
>   0,6,0
>   1,0,5
>   1,1,4
>   1,2,3
>   1,3,2
>   1,4,1
>   1,5,0
>   2,0,4
>   2,1,3
>   2,2,2
>   2,3,1
>   2,4,0
>   3,0,3
>   3,1,2
>   3,2,1
>   3,3,0
>   4,0,2
>   4,1,1
>   4,2,0
>   5,0,1
>   5,1,0
>   6,0,0

Looks about right?
Now try the bigger numbers, the resulting array is stored in `perms`.

If you explicitly want every number mentioned in the array, you can use some counters and math to get that kind of array in stead. E.g.:
`3,1,2` -> `[1,2,3],[4],[5,6]`
`2,0,4` -> `[1,2],[],[3,4,5,6]`

Here is a snippet using 6 blocks and 24 numbers:

> ...
>   7,2,2,10,0,3
>   7,2,2,10,1,2
>   7,2,2,10,2,1
>   7,2,2,10,3,0
>   7,2,2,11,0,2
>   7,2,2,11,1,1
>   7,2,2,11,2,0
>   7,2,2,12,0,1
>   7,2,2,12,1,0
>   7,2,2,13,0,0
>   7,2,3,0,0,12
>   7,2,3,0,1,11
>   7,2,3,0,2,10
>   ...

..but this list is endless.